# How to subtract HH:MM:SS.sss formatted data?

Tags: python

How to subtract the following format data in python

```
a =16:03:00.135  b =16:02:57:507
```

Please provide some inputs on this

```
>>> float(16:03:00.135) - float(16:02:57.507)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    float(16:03:00.135) - float(16:02:57.507)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: thats clearly hours:minutes:seconds ... you cannnot write `a=16:03:00.135`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "16:03:00.135"
b = "16:02:00.135"
def str2secs(s):
    h,m,s = map(float,s.split(":")) 
    return h*3600+m*60 + s
print str2secs(a) - str2secs(b)
```

the str2secs just splits the timestring into its parts and multiplies hours by the number of seconds in an hour, and it then multiplies minutes by the number of seconds in a minute ... then it adds up all the parts to get the total seconds for that timestring

Comment: Can you add some detail to explain what this code is doing? It's coming up in the LQP queue as-is.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.strptime` is designated to parse time:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d1 = datetime.strptime('16:03:00.135', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> d2 = datetime.strptime('16:02:57.507', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> d1 - d2
datetime.timedelta(0, 2, 628000)
```